# Re-instate formulas when deleted

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, circular-reference

## Context

I am trying to make a hassle-free multifamily rental analysis worksheet. The end user doesn't know anything about excel. The datapoints of one section are *unit types*, *number of units per type*, *monthly rent per unit*, and *annual rent per unit*. I would like the user to be able to enter the *monthly rent* and have the *annual rent* calculated or vise versa (assuming, in both cases, they've also entered the *number of units* per type). The formulas in question are more simple than you could have imagined:

*Monthly rent* = *Annual Rent* / *12* / *Number of units*

*Annual rent* = *Monthly rent* * *Number of Units* * *12*

I've enabled iterative calculation to allow me to keep a formula in each rent column, because they rely on each other for their calculation (**dependent formulas**). This works great but only for the first entry. If the user entered *monthly rent* data but would now like to instead enter *annual data*, the formula for the monthly calculation is gone. **However,** I was able to resolve this with some crafty code in `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` that I pasted below. This works perfectly. Whenever one is changed, the formula is inserted for the other, overwriting the user input--*unless*... one of the formulas was deleted instead of just changed.

## The Problem

I cannot find any information on how to insert a formula when a user deletes it. For example: Let's say the user had previously entered information for *monthly rent* and the worksheet automatically calculated annual rent. Now, when the user goes back to delete *monthly rent*, the monthly rent cell isn't reset, it's empty. The formula is no longer there and when they edit annual rent, the VBA doesn't reinstate the monthly rent formula.

I don't know:

- why the commented out ElseIf block doesn't work
- why sometimes deleting information entered into one of the dependent cells clears the other one and sometimes it doesn't
- why deleting the formula out of one and editing the other one doesn't reinstate the formula that was deleted. E.g. deleting monthly rent and then editing annual rent doesn't recreate the monthly rent formula

The ideal behavior, when the user deletes one of the dependent formulas, would be to have the cells return to their starting position with both circular formulas in place. It seems simply re-entering the formula when it is deleted should do the trick but surprisingly, I can't find any help on how to do that.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'Macro replaces formulas in circular reference cells
'This is to allow users to enter a piece of data in one
'column and have the other column automatically calculate,
'even if they had already entered data into the cell that
'calculates.
'
'FOR EXAMPLE: users can enter the monthly rent to have the
'annual rent calculate OR they can enter the annual rent to
'have the monthly rent calculate (assuming they have also
'provided number of units in the No. of Units column). This
'macro overwrites the cell contents of the unused column, allowing
'users to enter a monthly rent figure and see what the annual rent
'is but then to specify the annual rent and have the monthly rent
'column overwrite their previously entered figure

Dim AnnualRent, MonthlyRent As Range
Dim cll As Variant

'Dynamically set the ranges of interest, to allow users to
'add rows willy-nilly
Set AnnualRent = Range("R2:R" & Range("Total_Ann_Rent").Row - 1)
Set MonthlyRent = Range("P2:P" & Range("Total_Ann_Rent").Row - 1)

'It is necessary to disable event listening to prevent an infinite loop
Application.EnableEvents = False

'Handle subsequent changes to the ranges set above, specifically,
'to rebuild the circularity
For Each cll In Target.Cells
    With cll
        'Make a persistent formula for MonthlyRent
        If Not Intersect(cll, MonthlyRent) Is Nothing _
            And .Offset(0, 2).FormulaR1C1 <> "=RC[-2]*12*RC[-11]" Then

            .Offset(0, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]*12*RC[-11]"

'       'Reinstate the MonthlyRent when it's deleted
'        ElseIf Not Intersect(cll, MonthlyRent) Is Nothing _
'            And .Formula Is Nothing Then
'
'            .FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(RC[2]/12/RC[-9],0)"


        'Make a persistent formula for Annual Rent
        ElseIf Not Intersect(cll, AnnualRent) Is Nothing _
            And .Offset(0, -2).FormulaR1C1 <> "=IFERROR(RC[2]/12/RC[-9],0)" Then

            .Offset(0, -2).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(RC[2]/12/RC[-9],0)"

'        'Reinstate Annual Rent formula when it's deleted
'        ElseIf Not Intersect(cll, AnnualRent) Is Nothing _
'            And .formula Is Nothing Then
'
'            .Formula R1C1 = "=RC[-2]*12*RC[-11]"

        End If
    End With
Next cll

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: If you're using an event handler to respond to changes then do you even need the monthly/annual formulas?  When the user changes a monthly or annual amount you could directly update the other cell on that row.

Comment: Instead of `And .Formula Is Nothing Then` use  `And Len(.Formula) = 0 Then`.   "Formula" is just an empty string when a cell has no fomula.

Comment: FYI: I want to use formulas in the worksheet to allow the user to see what calculations the worksheet is performing, if they would like to. I know the worksheet is flawless but I must allow for others to verify it for themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better approach (since you're already using an event handler to respond to changes) might be to skip the formulas entirely, and instead when the user changes a monthly or annual amount directly just update the other cell on that row.

Alternatively if you want to continue with your current approach:

Instead of

```
 ... And .Formula Is Nothing Then
```

use

```
 ... And Len(.Formula) = 0 Then
```

"Formula" just returns an empty string when a cell has no formula.